# Play! Framework: Turning Raw SQL Query to JSON?

Tags: playframework-2.0

I'm executing raw SQL queries from my database and I want to transform them to JSON which I can pass into my templates. The JSON API Play offers seems to only work if you have a model class or have a json string. Building a model class seems to be too heavy weight for this. I want to build my JSON object with my java code, for example...

```
json.put("Key", "value")
json.put("Key1", "value1");
json.put("Key2", "value2");
```

I know that the Java JSON library allows me to do this, but I can't seem to pass it into my scala template. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

To change sql queries to Json, just make Scala map of those queries and than use play framework's play.api.libs.json package to convert it into json.
Documentation is provided on Play framework's [ScalaJson page](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaJson).